# Can I use multiple DOIs with PlumXMetrics() from pybliometrics

Tags: pybliometrics

Do you know how to use `pybliometrics.scopus.PlumXMetrics` with multiple DOIs at once?

I have a list of DOIs in a file text that I would like to automatically pass as identifiers. Right now, you can only enter manually one DOI as an identifier.

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import PlumXMetrics
plum = PlumXMetrics("10.1016/j.softx.2019.100263", id_type='doi')
```

Answer (score 0):

That is, unfortunately, not possible. Each retrieval API (to wich the PlumX Metrics API belongs) accepts only one endpoint. The solution to this is to simply iterate over each DOI.